# How to get the selected items in source control explorer?

Tags: vspackage, visual-studio-sdk

I'm writing a vspackage and while I can add things to the context menus in source control explorer, I don't know how to figure out the currently selected file(s).

For the solution explorer, I know I can do something like this:

```
var applicationObject = GetDTE2();
UIHierarchy hierarchy = applicationObject.ToolWindows.SolutionExplorer;
Array selectedItems = (Array)hierarchy.SelectedItems;
```

But looking at applicationObject.ActiveWindow gives me the source control explorer window, but I can't figure out any way to figure out what files are selected.

Comment: I don't think this is documented. The only way is to use UI Automation (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_UI_Automation) as the underlying controls used (winforms treeview + listview) are accessible.